# Mijoshop / Opencart if Category of Product

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Mijoshop which is a Opencart integration for Joomla. What I am currently looking to achieve is to display a specific div class in the header if a certain product or category is matched.

I've found this code which I've added to my category.tpl but without any luck or any of these being displayed:

```
    <? php if($category_id==20){
    echo "text1";}
    else
    {echo "text2"}
    ?>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php if($category['category_id'] == 20) { ?>
          echo "text1";
      } else {
          echo "text2";
      }
?>
```

The value should be called by **$category['category_id']** and you had some syntax errors:

- Space after ?
- No semi-colon after "text2"